# Simple MySQL Query Showing Error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute the following query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `developer_messenger`;
CREATE TABLE `developer_messenger` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But this simple query is showing me Error in PHP

> Could not get data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `developer_messenger` ( `id` int(10)
>   NOT NULL, `title` varchar(' at line 1

I am a newbie, Sorry if its silly,

Help Appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to run this in a PHP call or directly in SQL ?

Comment: Works for me.  See - http://rextester.com/ZTM29051

Comment: Can you show your complete php code where you run this query

Comment: Show your php code in which you are getting error?

Comment: in database sql it's working fine !  you should declare proper DataType for table's column !show your code from where you are trying to execute this query if not in database sql !

Comment: Yea, I found that the error is because of `magic_quotes_gpc` which is ON in PHP (Due to my some other code), Is it possible to turn it Off without writing anything into PHP file (Because I can only access it once a month due to some reasons), like- by changing mysql syntax or something? (Mainly It is escaping Quotes). Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In Response to your second question about magic_quotes:

```
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { //checks php ini if magic_quotes is not on
$title = addslashes($_POST['title']);  
}
else
{
$title = stripslashes($_POST['title']); 
}
```

`addslashes();` http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

`stripslashes();` http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

not sure if this helps but it might that way you dont have to change php.ini
just the `$data` that is to be entered into sql

Comment: Is there a way to implement the same without editing PHP.ini file or even the PHP file where my code is written(Due to some restrictions, I can't access it untill a few days), I.E. Directly in the MYSQL Query (Doing some changes there), escaping the unwanted slashes! Help Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct, Try exciting DROP and CREATE one by one.

This code may help you.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `developer_messenger` ( 
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
`title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`message` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`date_time` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Table MyGuests created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```